# php mysql sum if exists in another table

Tags: php, mysql, exists

How do I do this?

I have this table:

Table1

```
|--ID--|--Stars--|--Name--|
|   1  |    3    |  Pe    |
|   2  |    5    |  Me    |
|   3  |    7    |  Fe    |
|------|---------|--------|
```

Table2

```
|--ID--|--Teams--|--Age---|--Name--|
|   1  |    A    |  20    |  Pe    |
|   2  |    A    |  20    |  Me    |
|   3  |    A    |  20    |  Pe    |
|------|---------|--------|--------|
```

I want the sum of stars in Table1 where Name exists in Table2 and Teams=A and Age=20. (3+5=8stars)

I use this, but how do I only count the stars where the name in Table1 matches the name in Table2?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(Stars) AS starsum FROM Table1 WHERE EXISTS (select * from Table2 WHERE Teams = 'A' AND Age = '20')");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
$antalstjernerhold = $row['starsum'];
```

Comment: You need to learn about [JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)s

Answer (score 2):

Try this query

```
   SELECT SUM(t1.Stars) AS starsum 
   FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2
   ON t1.Name=t2.Name AND t2.Teams='A' AND t2.Age=20
```

You have to use `inner join` to get desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your query this way:

```
SELECT SUM(Stars) AS starsum
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE
  EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Table2 t2
    WHERE
      T2.Name=T1.Name
      AND T2.Teams='A'
      AND t2.Age=20
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT SUM(Stars) AS starsum
FROM Table1
WHERE Name IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.Name 
    FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2
    WHERE t1.Name = t2.Name
    AND t2.Teams = 'A'
    AND t2.Age = 20
)
");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
$antalstjernerhold = $row['starsum'];
```

The query is using below subquery which will fetch the names belonging to both tables and have teams as A and Age 20 & then using those names we get the sum of stars

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.Name 
FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2
WHERE t1.Name = t2.Name
AND t2.Teams = 'A'
AND t2.Age = 20
```